# Facebook unsafe URL error fix

Tags: facebook

I have a site and a Facebook page. When I share a new post on my page I get an error:

> **You can't post this because it has a blocked link**
>
> The content you're trying to share includes a link that our security systems detected to be unsafe

[image]

When I tried my link on the Facebook debugger page I got this message:

[image]

Can you please tell me that how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to fix this is to click the link provided in that dialog.

> If you think you're seeing this by mistake, **please let us know**

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have a Wordpress site. Add Jetpack plugin and enable the sharing tool that comes with it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Today i install Jetpack plugin but still problem is not solved here is a list of my all plugins active and deactivate as you can see here if http://i.imgur.com/XOrA1ui.jpg  which plugins need to remove or need to install please tell me so i can fix this i will be very thankful to you

Comment: Deactivate all facebook plugins and enable the sharing tool on Jetpack. Ensure you configure it properly. If you are still having issues after implementing the task above, install "Add This" or "ShareThis".

Comment: Thank you very much to reply i back to me i really appreciate here i install a jetpag plugin as you can see opranks single post jetpage share button but i got this error now please tell me how can i fix this

Comment: Here is a image link http://i.imgur.com/wqAaRUr.png

Comment: Dear Kali. Have you tried the other two plugin(AddThis and ShareThis)?

Comment: Hi Inspired Michael,

Comment: Hi Inspired Michael,

Comment: Hello. Kindly answer these questions below: What version of WordPress do you have? Have you scanned your website for any vulnerability? It seems you have banned links on your site. My SkypeID is mikeoki